# Will using the console mark my account as suspicious even if I'm not logged in?

Tags: torchlight-2

As was noted in [this question](/questions/85552/how-do-i-enable-the-console), using the console in Torchlight II will mark your account as "suspicious" in multiplayer. If I'm not signed in at the time that I use the console, and then disable it before I sign in again, will the game remember that I used it in the past?

Comment: This is not really a "server monitors you" game. You have complete control over your save files and game mods, so it's far more likely that using anything built into the game (i.e., the console) will mark your account, which means both offline and online. You will probably have to resort to something else if you want to avoid being marked.

Comment: That certainly makes sense, but I still want a definitive answer before I try. The main reason that I asked this is because in the question I linked, the answer says you "risk" being flagged, implying that it doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 3):

When using the console and using a command that flags you as suspicious (I would assume commands like `godmode` or `levelup`) this flag is **stored in your save file**.

So the next time you sign in, the game can very easily see if you 'cheated' or not.

Mind you that with a hex editor you could simply remove the suspicious flag from your save file so you're not labeled a cheater.

Comment: The linked post apparently talks about the first game, not this one.

Comment: @JeffMercado You're absolutely right so I removed the link, I've seen it in another post on the `Runic Games forums` but I can't seem to find it (mainly because their search form never works for me), if i come accross it again, I'll put it here.